# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BlazingSQL' Error after Installing RAPIDS with 'python rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/install_rapids.py

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, modulenotfounderror, rapids, blazingsql

**Hello,
I installed successfully following script on Google Colab for
installing RAPIDS:
'python rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/install_rapids.py '

The options are 'stable' and 'nightly'. Leaving it blank or adding any other words will default to stable.
The option are default blank or 'core'. By default, we install RAPIDSAI and BlazingSQL. The 'core' option will install only RAPIDSAI and not include BlazingSQL,

!python rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/install_rapids.py stable

```
import os
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_NVVM'] = '/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/lib64/libnvvm.so'
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_LIBDEVICE'] = '/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/libdevice/'
os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'] = '/usr/local'
```

But I am getting following Error for BlazingSQL Module:
ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()

```
----> 1 from BlazingSQL import BlazingContext

2 import cudf

3 bc = BlazingContext()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BlazingSQL'
```

Can I get any help? BlazingSQL should be installed successfully.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the template, as BlazingSQL was deprecated in favor of dask-sql in 21.12.  You will need to update your code to dask-sql in the current and future releases.  This should be an easy transition as they used a similar API.  You can see it in action with the notebooks found here.

- https://github.com/rapidsai-community/notebooks-contrib/tree/main/getting_started_materials/hello_worlds/dask-sql
- https://github.com/rapidsai-community/notebooks-contrib/blob/main/community_tutorials_and_guides/dask-sql/dsql_vs_pyspark_netflow.ipynb

As of writing, Dask-sql is still experimental with Colab, and we're testing it with Sagemaker Studio very soon.

In the mean time, you can still install an older, BlazingSQL-compatible version of RAPIDS, such as 21.08 or 21.10, by manually editing the install script options to do so before running it. **This will have to be done right after the first cell, where you git pull the repo,** as I've found that you lose Colab's easy file navigation and file editing features when we restart the kernel.

1. Navigate, in the file browser on the left side to `content/rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/install_rapids.py` and open the file.  it should pop open on the right side of your browser tab.
2. change Line 41 in  from:

`output = subprocess.Popen(["conda install -y --prefix /usr/local -c "+release[0]+" -c nvidia -c conda-forge python=3.7 cudatoolkit=11.2 "+pkg+"="+release[1]+" llvmlite gcsfs openssl dask-sql"], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,`

to:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["conda install -y --prefix /usr/local -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge python=3.7 cudatoolkit=11.2 rapids-blazing=21.10 llvmlite gcsfs openssl"], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
```

3. Save it
4. Run the rest of the install cells as normal

Comment: I made changes to line 41 with "output = subprocess.Popen(["conda install -y --prefix /usr/local -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge python=3.7 cudatoolkit=11.2 rapids-blazing=21.10 llvmlite gcsfs openssl dask-sql"], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, ".   But I got error from execution of "!python rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/install_rapids.py stable --no-pin ".

Comment: SpecsConfigurationConflictError: Requested specs conflict with configured specs.
  requested specs:
    - cudatoolkit=11.2
    - dask-sql
    - gcsfs
    - llvmlite
    - openssl
    - rapids-blazing=21.10
  pinned specs:
    - python=3.7
Use 'conda config --show-sources' to look for 'pinned_specs' and 'track_features'
configuration parameters.  Pinned specs may also be defined in the file
/usr/local/conda-meta/pinned.

Comment: remove dask-sql.  i'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you.  Errors are gone.. blazingsql can be successfully imported.